# How can I copy variables of type Option?

Tags: rust, enums, copy

This code has been causing me a lot of trouble for the past few hours. The idea is simple: I want to create a chessboard using the following code:

```
#[derive(Copy)]
struct Board([[Option<Chesspiece>; 8]; 8]);
impl Board {
    fn draw(&self) {
        //-
    }
}

enum Chesspiece {
    Pawn,
    Tower,
    Knight,
    Bishop,
    King,
    Queen,
}

fn empty_board() -> Board {
    let x = [[None; 8]; 8];
    Board(x)
}

fn main() {
    let board = empty_board();
    board.draw();
}
```

The error message I get when trying to compile is:

```
error[E0204]: the trait `Copy` may not be implemented for this type
 --> txt.rs:1:10
  |
1 | #[derive(Copy)]
  |          ^^^^
2 | struct Board([[Option<Chesspiece>; 8]; 8]);
  |              ---------------------------- this field does not implement `Copy`
  |
note: the `Copy` impl for `[[Option<Chesspiece>; 8]; 8]` requires that `Chesspiece: Copy`
 --> txt.rs:2:14
  |
2 | struct Board([[Option<Chesspiece>; 8]; 8]);
  |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  = note: this error originates in the derive macro `Copy` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

Is there some way I can fix my code. My idea is that the empty board should be an 8x8 array where every single field has no value, e.g. is an empty array. I am also aware that my code may be fairly unconventional which is why it might not work.

Comment: Hint: "requires that Chesspiece: Copy" means `#[derive(Copy)]` on `Chesspiece`

Comment: Tip: You probably want an `fn new() -> Board` that creates a populated board rather than having to mess around with internals via `Board(...)`. Even better, `new()` could return a board in the standard configuration, while `new_blank()` could return one with no pieces.

Comment: You probably also want `enum Color` and then `Option<(Color,Chesspiece)>` instead, or perhaps `enum Color { White(Chesspiece), Black(Chesspiece), Empty }`.

Answer (score 1):

As [@tadman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87189/tadman) pointed out, you need to add a `Copy` implementation for `Chesspiece`. To be able to `#[derive(Copy)]`, you also need to implement `Clone` for both types:

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
struct Board(...);
//...
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
enum Chesspiece { ... }
```

To be able to derive `Copy` (or `Clone`), all fields in your struct/enum must also implement that trait, otherwise the compiler can't know how to implement it.

[Full working example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=216a5e68fe849ae655328be5b1430fbd)

Comment: Oh I just realized by looking at your code that I misunderstood the way #[derive(Clone, Copy)] works. I only used #[allow(dead_code)] before and thought that was something you include only once at the beginning of a file, like imports etc *facepalm*. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Susp1cious np :), these are macros, check out https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-06-macros.html for a more complete overview of the feature